# C# шаблон проверка типа T

Tags: c#, generics

Есть такой Метод

```
List<T> GetAll<T>() where T : IModel
```

И набор классов реализующих интерфейс IModel

Вот использование такого метода:

```
var users = GetAll<User>();
var custommers = GetAll<Custommer>();
```

Как мне в методе GetAll проверить какому именно классу принадлежит T? Я пробовал так, но компилятор ругается

```
List<T> GetAll<T>() where T : IModel
{
if(T.GetType() == User)
//some Code
}
```

Comment: `if (typeof(T) == typeof(User)){...}` ?

Comment: да уж, глупая ошибка,  забыл что .GetType используется на уровне экземпляров -_-, будете выводить в ответ или я сам?

Comment: Но тут нужно остановиться и задуматься, может всё-таки сделать отдельные методы, типа `GetAll<T>() where T : User`

Comment: а зачем это нужно?

Comment: @Grundy, чтобы в зависимости от типа возвращать список нужных значений(у меня по крайней мере было так). Пример GetAll<Person>() Возвращал бы список всех объектов типа Person, а GetAll<Info>() возвращал бы список всех  объектов типа Info

Comment: @babyhn9, для этого generic, а зачем внутри метода проверять тип?

Comment: @Grundy потому что T шёл, считай как параметр, просто чтобы не писать
GetAll(Typeof(type)) каждый раз, решил пихать через Generic'и, и уже внутри метода, использовать typeof

Comment: да, так я и не понял зачем? Если внутри generic функции ты проверяешь тип и делаешь разные действия в зависимости от проверки - скорее всего тебе не нужен generic

Comment: Странно, работая с `GetType` еще и `typeof` использовать до кучи, когда есть уже специально `is` для этого. раз уже начинает прибегать к тому, что используется приведения типов, проверка тот или не тот, и т. д. и т. п. Тут скорее беда в архитектуре программы. потому что везде тулить приведения, там где нужно и не нужно, это чревато просиданием производительности и замедлением программы в целом.

Comment: @And, да знаю, это ещё и отсутствие масштабируемости, т.к при расширении кол-ва классов, каждый раз, нужно было приходить в этот метод, и дописывать, сейчас, теоретически, я знаю, как исправить это, но на тот момент, я и представить не мог, как упростить процесс

Comment: что-то не обратил внимания на дату :)

Comment: И не понятно еще одно, зачем вы тогда делаете динамику, когда потом опять используете поиски объектов и сравнения, не проще тогда уже без динамики обойтись и юзать статику.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С# язык с сильной типизацией и имеет набор методов и операторов, позволяющих получить тип Сущности. Есть метод object.GetType который возвращает тип существующего объекта.

```
var user = new User();
user.GetType(); // вернёт объект типа type который описывает тип User.
```

А так же существует оператор `typeof` который работает на уровне классов:

```
var user = new User();
typeof(user/*objectName*/); // ERROR
typeof(User/*className*/);// всё ок
```

Решение моей задачи:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Tarif))
                //some code
else
                //other code
```